# Php написание Блога

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TB0XhsWpY-M)

Писал Блог по этому видео уроку, всё было хорошо подключил БД, но при создание поста пишет вот что (написал заголовок текста и сам текст, и при нажатии создать)

[image: Ошибка]

Полный проект -> [Проект](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OulzB8YVrEZSW92Sm9VDiDpPPIpgKokK/view?usp=sharing)

Логин для захода в аккаунт на блоге: admin@localhost Пароль: 1

```
   <?php
 
class ctrlIndex extends ctrl {
 
 
    function index() {
        $this->posts = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY ctime DESC")->all();
        $this->out('posts.php');
    }
 
    function login() {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $user = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?",$_POST['mail'],md5($_POST['pass']))->assoc();
            if ($user) {
                $_key = md5(microtime().rand(0,10000));
                $_time = time()+86400*30;
                setcookie('uid', $user['id'], $_time);
                setcookie('key', $_key, $_time);
                $this->db->query("UPDATE admin SET cookie = ? WHERE id = ?",$_key,$user['id']);
                header("Location: /");
            } else
                $this->error = 'Неправильный емейл или пароль';
        }
        $this->out('login.php');
    }
 
    function logout() {
        setcookie('uid','',0);
        setcookie('key','',0);
        $this->user = false;
        header("Location: /");
    }
 
    function add() {
        if (!$this->user) return header("Location: /");
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO post(title,post,ctime) VALUES(?,?,?)",htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']), $_POST['post'],time());
            header("Location: /");
        }
        $this->out('add.php');
 
    }
 
    function edit($id) {
        if (!$this->user) return header("Location: /");
 
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->db->query("UPDATE post SET title=?, post=? WHERE id=?",htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']), $_POST['post'], $id);
            print_r($res);
            header("Location: /");
        }
        else {
            $this->post = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ?",$id)->assoc();
            $this->out('add.php');
        }
    }
 
    function del($id) {
        if (!$this->user) return header("Location: /");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM post WHERE id = ?",$id);
        header("Location: /");
    }
 
 
    function post($id) {
        $this->post = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ?",$id)->assoc();
        $this->comments = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postid = ? ORDER BY id DESC",$id)->all();
        $this->out('post.php');
    }
 
    function addComment($postid) {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO comment(name,post,postid) VALUES(?,?,?)",htmlspecialchars($_POST['a-name']), htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']),$postid);
            setcookie('name', $_POST['a-name'], time()+86400*30);
            header("Location: /?post/".intval($postid));
        }
        // $this->out('add.php');
    }
 
    function delComment($commid,$postid) {
        if (!$this->user) return header("Location: /");
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM comment WHERE id = ?",$commid);
        header("Location: /?post/".intval($postid));
    }
}
```

Comment: Он же вам черным по-английски пишет: для поля `author` нет дефолтного значения. В запросе insert добавьте значение для поля и будет хорошо.

Comment: @IvanDudarev может я и не правильно изменил, но посты так и не добавляются

Comment: Вероятно, изменилась и ошибка?

Comment: @IvanDudarev выше я обновил, add функция должна добавлять, но что-то там не так.

Comment: Ссылка на проект закрыта, запрашивать доступ лень

Comment: @IvanDudarev разве закрыта? Странно, вроде открывал

Comment: @IvanDudarev открыл доступ к проекту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не увидел, что вы добавили значение для поля `author`

```php
<?php
 
class ctrlIndex extends ctrl {
 
 
    // ...
 
    function add() {
        if (!$this->user) return header("Location: /");
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO post(title,post,ctime,author) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']), $_POST['post'],time(), $this->user['id']); // или $this->user['email'], или что там нужно записать.
            header("Location: /");
        }
        $this->out('add.php');
 
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: [Ошибка](https://imgur.com/a/6Hqa8be)

Comment: Значит, $this->user у вас массив. Что вы хотите записать в поле `author`? ID юзера, его логин или email? Где хранится это значение в массиве $this->user?

Comment: User  скорее всего.

Comment: вы лучший)) первый раз у вас была ошибка что три знака ? а нужно было 4 как вы уже и выправили, остальные функции работают